# Проектирование и программирование приложения

Tags: веб-программирование

Очередной вопрос назрел. В кратце, есть идея приложения и есть задумка по реализации его. Но вопрос в том, на чем лучше его реализовывать. Исходные хотелки, это то, чтобы его могли использовать как и с помощью браузера(веб интерфейс), так и с помощью десктоп приложения и мобильный вариант, например, андроид. Как лучше поступить, разрабатывать отдельно для каждого варианта свое или же разработать веб версию, а приложения проектировать как веббраузер подгружая страницу с вебприложением и адаптируя ее?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: и так и так хорошо, всё очень сильно зависит от того что именно вы делаете.

Comment: Просто приложение сбора,выдачи обмена данными. В основном сбор, хранение и предоставление в удобном для пользователя виде.

Comment: если не предполагается тяжелой обработки на стороне клиента, то имхо вам лучше\проще\быстрей\дешевле - реализовать в виде вэб приложения